# GAS: how can I increase the size of the scroll panel?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I've create this scroll panel:

```
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 300);
   var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
   scroll.add(panel);
   app.add(scroll);  
   spreadsheet.show(app);
```

But I can't get this scroll panel bigger than `setPixelSize(500, 300);` because, in this case, the `submit` button is not shown. How can I increase the size of the panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget you can define the size of the uiApp instance itself, it will probably solve your problem...

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(800).setWidth(1500);
  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 300);
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  scroll.add(panel);
  app.add(scroll);  
  spreadsheet.show(app);
}
```